POWER BI, want to do some unpivoting kind of task in power bi visulaisation
i have a data like this
enter image description here
And i want to make it something like this
enter image description here
ty_ - this year
ly_ - last year
This is a part of a visualisation, please note any changes cant be made to the data. I just want to ask , can we do something like this without changing or updating the data?

Can you be clear you are not importing the data? you can use a matrix table to pivot it, but best to do in Power Query if you can
